# Is it possible to get a list of all the pages where I authenticated with my Google OpenID

Tags: openid, google-openid

From the usability perpective, it is perfect to authenticate with google at all type of pages with my Google OpenID (for example on stackexchange).

But I do not really know what happens when I do so. Especially I would like to get a list for all the pages where I authenticated myself with OpenID with google.

Does such a list exist? Or do I get something wrong with the concept of OpenID. Is it possible to detract the authentication for specific sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see this on your Google Account page
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions